# SQL Query - solving duplicate data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Here are the 2 tables I am using currently with some example data:

```
Finances        
FinanceID   Variation   Total
    1          0        £1,000.00 
    5          1        £250.00 
    24         2        £500.00
```

A Project can contain multiple Finances, Variation 0 is the Original Order, and each Finance line here after is 1 greater than the previous.

```
Application         
ApplicationID   ApplicationNumber   PercentageComplete  Value
      5                 1                 20%           £200.00 
      17                2                 50%           £300.00 
      35                3                 75%           £250.00 
      91                4                 90%           £150.00
```

The Application table above references the Original Finance Line, NOT the Variations

and here is an example of my problem which I will explain in more detail after:

```
Application 5   PercentageComplete  Value
Contains no Variations      

Application 17        PercentageComplete    Value
Contains Variation 1         40%            £100.00 

Application 35        PercentageComplete    Value
Contains Variation 1        100%            £150.00 
Contains Variation 2        25%             £125.00 

Application 91        PercentageComplete    Value
Contains Variation 1        100%            £0.00   
Contains Variation 2        60%             £175.00
```

- An Application can contain multiple Variations
- Once an Application contains a Variation, it needs to be automatically added to the next Application that is created.

So using the above example, the user would manually add Variation 1 to Application 17, enter its percentage complete, and the the value would be calculated automatically

**MY PROBLEM:**

Now for Application 35,  I want the variation line from the previous Application added to this one AUTOMATICALLY, however when the infomation is edited (now at 100%) i do not want this to affect Application 17.

is my only option to keep duplicating the data for each Variation Line or is there a more efficient method someone could help me with? I have tried writing a Query to do this also, which was a lot more difficult than i anticipated so if this is the only method, some pointers or an example would be great help.

For the Query, I created this table to try it:

```
VariationLine   ApplicationID   VariationID PreviousPercentage  NewPercentage   Value
      1              17             1              0%                 40%      £100.00 
      2              35             1              40%                100%     £150.00 
      3              35             2              0%                 25%      £125.00 
      4              91             1              100%               100%     £0.00   
      5              91             2              25%                60%      £175.00
```

If I was to add a 5th Application, then I would need to insert the 2 previous VariationLines for the new Project (4 and 5)

**Short Version of my problem:**

I have an 4 Application's... The 1st has no Variations and just its own cost. For the 2nd Application the user manually adds Variation 1 with a percentage complete of 40% (£100.00)... when the user creates the 3rd Application, I would like SQL Server to automatically add the 1st Variation to this Project, as a new Variation line so that i can ammend the percentage complete and not affect the previous Application

**Entity Relationship Diagram**

[image]

Comment: i am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: TMI, Try using a minimal example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Better understanding of table relation/join will help to fix ur problem. Finances and Application is linked but how?

Comment: Added automaitcally? How do you add the original variation. Through a program? Do you want a T-SQL solution or an program solution?

Comment: are you able to add fields to your tables? Otherwise just add dates to when a variation was added and when an application was added, if the variation was added after the application, don't apply it in your calculations

Comment: a variation is created when a finance sheet is added. This is here as the finance sheet contains multiple fields, which are calculated together in the variations table. so the user has no control over the data added into the Variations table. For the Variation Line Table, the first time a variation is added, this is done manually by the user, the Application that follows that would automatically insert a replica line from the previous... however the previous percentage would update from the current percentage from Application 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a view to first determine the the previous VariationLines based upon a changedate column, and when a new Application is added, then this view below would select all of the Applications Variations based on the previous Application. If the Application was a 1st, then nothing is added at first, a user has the option to add in Variations to the Application at any point in time.

```
CREATE VIEW NextApplicationVariations AS
SELECT variationid, 
       (SELECT TOP (1) applicationid 
        FROM   dbo.applications 
        ORDER  BY changedate DESC) AS ApplicationID, 
       (SELECT TOP (1) applicationnumber 
        FROM   dbo.applications 
        ORDER  BY changedate DESC) AS ApplicationCounter, 
       variationpercentage, 
       0                           AS VariationValue, 
       variationpercentage         AS PreviousPercentage, 
       projectreference, 
       totalvariationvalue, 
       0                           AS VariationRetention 
FROM   dbo.variationline 
WHERE  ( projectreference = (SELECT TOP (1) projectreference 
                             FROM   dbo.projectcosts 
                             ORDER  BY changedate DESC) ) 
       AND ( applicationcounter = (SELECT TOP (1) applicationnumber 
                                   FROM   dbo.applications 
                                   ORDER  BY changedate DESC) - 1 )
```

Now all thats left to do is insert the new lines based upon this view, and now this query is ran in a view, I can use the NOT EXISTS in the query to determine whether the latest Application has had its VariationLines added automatically

```
--INSERT PREVIOUS VARIATIONS INTO NEW APPLICATIONS 
INSERT INTO variationline 
            (variationid, 
             applicationid, 
             applicationcounter, 
             variationpercentage, 
             variationvalue, 
             previouspercentage, 
             projectreference, 
             totalvariationvalue, 
             variationretention) 
SELECT nextvariationline.variationid, 
       nextvariationline.applicationid, 
       nextvariationline.applicationcounter, 
       nextvariationline.variationpercentage, 
       nextvariationline.variationvalue, 
       nextvariationline.previouspercentage, 
       nextvariationline.projectreference, 
       nextvariationline.totalvariationvalue, 
       nextvariationline.variationretention 
FROM   nextvariationline 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   variationline 
                   WHERE  nextvariationline.applicationid = 
                         variationline.applicationid)
```